# How could you do to not show rows to users that are in a specific table

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a website where users can post links and interact with them.

All users are shown a table with all the links of the users.

But I need to ask a question, for when a user interacts with a link, that link will not be shown again.
That is, when a user clicks on a link, the link disappears only for the user who clicked

I have done the following.

I have the table (users) where all the users are stored.

```
Table1 (users):
----------------
| id | username |
----------------
|  1 |  user1   |
----------------
|  2 |  user2   |
----------------
|  3 |  user3   |
----------------
```

This is the second table where all the links are stored

```
Table2 (links):
----------------
| id | urls |
----------------
|  1 |  url1   |
----------------
|  2 |  url2   |
----------------
|  3 |  url3   |
----------------
```

Now suppose that (USER2 of table 1 (users)) clicked on the following links (URL1 and URL2 of table2 (links)).

When the user clicks on an url, the following values are stored in a third table as follows:

```
Table3 (blockuser):
-----------------------
| id | idLinks | users |
-----------------------
|  1 |    1    | user2 |
------------------------
|  2 |    2    | user2 |
-----------------------
```

Now I would like the table that contains all the links to be shown to each user in the following way.
This is what I want to achieve:

```
        User1:                    User2:                   User3:
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
| TABLE: ALL LINKS |      | TABLE: ALL LINKS |     | TABLE: ALL LINKS |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  ID   |  URLS    |      |  ID   |  URLS    |     |  ID   |  URLS    |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  1    |  url1    |      |  3    |  url3    |     |  1    |  url1    | 
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  2    |  url2    |                               |  1    |  url2    |
--------------------                               --------------------
|  3    |  url3    |                               |  1    |  url3    |
--------------------                               --------------------
```

And this is what I have been able to achieve.

```
        User1:                    User2:                   User3:
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
| TABLE: ALL LINKS |      | TABLE: ALL LINKS |     | TABLE: ALL LINKS |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  ID   |  URLS    |      |  ID   |  URLS    |     |  ID   |  URLS    |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  3    |  url3    |      |  3    |  url3    |     |  3    |  url3    | 
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
```

That is, when a user clicks on a link, the link is no longer displayed for all users.

But what I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on a link, the link will stop showing, only for the user who clicked on the link.....

This is the code I have to show the table:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    links
LEFT JOIN
    blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id
WHERE
    blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
```

Comment: `blockuser.idweb` doesn't exist in the schema you mention in the first code block in the body of your question - did you possibly mean `blockuser.idw`?

Comment: Can you improve the explanation of your goals, it is some confusing now. Also include the structure of your tables. The query you have made will return next rows: `(website.id=1, website.urls=url1, blockuser.id=null, blockuser.idw=null, blockuser.users=null)` and `(website.id=3, website.urls=url3, blockuser.id=null, blockuser.idw=null, blockuser.users=null)`. Info about website2 is filtered beacuse it have a match with blockuser table.

Comment: You are not clearly saying what you want. Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples. Read & act on [mcve]. PS You can clearly say what rows a base table holds or query result should hold by finishing/fixing a sentence like this: (ID #1, URLS, ID #2, ...) rows where (u.ID, u.USERNAME) is in Users & (...) is in Blockuser & ... u.ID <> g.ID ... & ID #1 = b.ID & .... You can use such a specification to help you make a more general statement about your needs that you can google & use as an intro and/or title.

Comment: What is `idw`??

Comment: I have already edited the question.
what happens is that I am new to this platform and new to programming.
My apologies to all.

Comment: Why don't you just prepopulate the user-links table with every possible row, and delete them when the user clicks? That way a simple inner join will cause only unclicked links to show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it. This is the correct answer in case someone is interested in the future.

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT idLinks FROM blockuser WHERE idUsers = 2)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT idLinks FROM blockuser WHERE users = 'user2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made next query, it will return the set of URLs that are available for each users.

```
SELECT
    users.username, GROUP_CONCAT(links.urls) AS availableWebsites
FROM
    users
CROSS JOIN
    links
LEFT JOIN
    blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id AND blockuser.users = users.username
WHERE
    blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
GROUP BY
    users.id, users.username;
```

Example of output for your set:

```
username availableWebsites
user1    url2,url1,url3
user2    url3
user3    url1,url3,url2
```

**UPDATE**

After reading updates on your question, and doing some modifications on the previous query, you can get a table with the relations of users and the urls they can access at a specific time, like this:

```
SELECT
    users.username, links.urls AS availableLink
FROM
    users
CROSS JOIN
    links
LEFT JOIN
    blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id AND blockuser.users = users.username
WHERE
    blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
```

An example of output for this query will be:

```
username availableLink
user1    url1
user1    url2
user1    url3
user2    url3
user3    url1
user3    url2
user3    url3
```

Even more, if you only want the links available to one user, you can do something like this:

```
SET @user = "user1";

SELECT
    users.username, links.urls AS availableLink
FROM
    users
CROSS JOIN
    links
LEFT JOIN
    blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id AND blockuser.users = users.username
WHERE
    blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
AND
    users.username = @user;
```

Comment: Hi. No answer should contain "since your goals are not exactly defined right now". The question is not clear. So it merits a comment asking for a clarifying edit, not an answer. Answers to unclear questions make a mess of comments & versions. And a non-comprehensive "guide" is not an answer anyway.

Comment: You are right, was just trying to help a little, i asked for better explanation, will update the answer or delete it, in case the question is not updated.

Comment: For more info see [answer] & hits googling with site:meta.stackoverfow.com or site:meta.stackexchange.com.